# Is there any framework algorithm development (testing / benchmarking)?

Tags: software-development, software-testing, algorithms, benchmarking

In relations to posts like [TDD like approach to Algorithmic problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339855/tdd-like-approach-to-algorithmic-problems), **is there any framework that can be used for developing algorithms** (where by "framework" I meant some sets of utilities that can sustain common/best practices)?

I am thinking the features needed would be :

- run tests to check correctness of results (unit tests)
- run jobs that call run the algorithm and collect metrics (memory / time)
- snapshot the current version of the source code and link it to the metric collected

If you know any, please specify the language also.

Comment: I presume that you are looking for [tag:cross-platform] & [tag:gratis] solutions?

Comment: @Mawg no,  not necessarily

Comment: Maybe you should mention that in the question (as not everyone will read this comment)? You could say “gratis preferred, but I could budget up to $xxx”. If operating system is important, mention that do. Take a look at [ask]. I don’t meant mean to be rude, it's just that the more info you give, the more you help us to help you.